# sqlnet.ora SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

Tags: oracle, configuration, parameters

```
SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)
```

This is oracle configuration file parameter.
What's the NTS meaning? NetWork Service? Windows NT Service? What's NTS abbr&&Full name?

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle Documentation Link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28317/sqlnet.htm#BIIDAFFD) :

```
Authentication Methods Available with Oracle Net Services: 

NONE - for no authentication methods, including Windows native operating system authentication (to use Windows native operating system authentication, set this parameter to nts). When SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES is set to none, a valid user name and password can be used to access the database.

ALL - for all authentication methods

NTS - for Windows native operating system authentication
```

Comment: Your answer is right,but i aready know before.I just want to find the NTS meaning for?Or some word abbr,it seems like NTS is just NTS,no abbr.Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I suspect is stands for Windows **NTS** ecurity. Before Windows 2000, the server product line of Windows was called NT.

Answer (score 0):

NTS [means](https://books.google.ru/books?id=ZxEL-FO4u7wC&pg=PA241&dq=%22nts%20(nt%20security)%22) NT Security

where NT [means](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_NT) New Technology